# getting error "lessphp fatal error: failed to parse passed in variable @heading_font_weight:"

Tags: css, wordpress, lessphp

My wordpress site is showing error-
"lessphp fatal error: failed to parse passed in variable @heading_font_weight:"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely preloading old cached less files for compilation that had errors during previous compilation (in most cases you can ignore them if your styling comes out right).

Enable less compilation during your website development, testing or customization and disable when launching it live. Don't forget to clear cache (also check your theme folder for cached less files - depending on theme some may be automatically saved there), clear your browser cache and reload the page.